# treeExplainer algorithm intuition

Tags: random-forest, decision-trees, xgboost, explainable-ai, shap

I'm reading the [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-019-0138-9.epdf?shared_access_token=RCYPTVkiECUmc0CccSMgXtRgN0jAjWel9jnR3ZoTv0O81kV8DqPb2VXSseRmof0Pl8YSOZy4FHz5vMc3xsxcX6uT10EzEoWo7B-nZQAHJJvBYhQJTT1LnJmpsa48nlgUWrMkThFrEIvZstjQ7Xdc5g%3D%3D) about the treeExplainer; the pseudo-code of Algorithm 1 is a bit cryptical as most of the variables are not even defined (same with sampling and all details involved).
Is there a more intuitive explanation of how the algorithm works, at a high-level?

Comment: Maybe try https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shap.html

Answer (score 1):

The paper you refer to actually states the following intuition:

> Algorithm 1 estimates $E[f(X)|do(X_S = x_S )]$ by recursively following the decision path for $x$ if the split feature is in $S$, and taking the weighted average of both branches if the split feature is not in $S$.

It seems to be a slight modification of the original description in [arxiv 1706.06060](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06060):

> For a tree model $E[f(x) | x_S]$ can be estimated  recursively using
>   Algorithm 1, where $v$ is a vector of node values, which takes the value
>   $internal$ for internal nodes. The vectors $a$ and $b$ represent the left
>   and right node indexes for each internal node. The vector $t$ contains
>   the thresholds for each internal node, and $d$ is a vector of indexes of
>   the features used for splitting in internal nodes. The vector $r$
>   represents the cover of each node (how many data samples fall in that
>   subtree).

I presume $S$ is an item in the set of all subsets of N features.